# 404 Not Found error when running Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am developing a simple Flask app, based on this example: 
https://gist.github.com/cuibonobo/8696392#apache

Below is the folder structure:

```
flaskapp:
   app:
      __init__.py
      static:
          css:
              main.css
      templates:
          404.html
          base.html
          forms:
              macros.html
          register.html
          users:
              login.html
              profile.html
          register.html
      users:
         __init__py
         constants.py
         decorators.py
         forms.py
         models.py
         views.py
app.db
config.py
run.py
shell.py
```

run.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

shell.py:
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import os
    import readline
    from pprint import pprint

```
from flask import *
from app import *

os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = 'True'
```

views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, g, session, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from app import db
from app.users.forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
from app.users.models import User
from app.users.decorators import requires_login

mod = Blueprint('users', __name__, url_prefix='/users')


@mod.route('/')
@requires_login
def home():
return render_template("users/profile.html", user=g.user)

@mod.before_request
def before_request():
"""
pull user's profile from the database before every request are treated
"""
g.user = None
if 'user_id' in session:
  g.user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])

@mod.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  """
  Login form
  """
  form = LoginForm(request.form)
  # make sure data are valid, but doesn't validate password is right
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    # we use werzeug to validate user's password
    if user and check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
      # the session can't be modified as it's signed, 
      # it's a safe place to store the user id
      session['user_id'] = user.id
      flash('Welcome %s' % user.name)
      return redirect(url_for('users.home'))
    flash('Wrong email or password', 'error-message')
  return render_template("users/login.html", form=form)

@mod.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
  """
  Registration Form
 """
 form = RegisterForm(request.form)
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    # create an user instance not yet stored in the database
    user = User(name=form.name.data, email=form.email.data, \
      password=generate_password_hash(form.password.data))
    # Insert the record in our database and commit it
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

    # Log the user in, as he now has an id
    session['user_id'] = user.id

    # flash will display a message to the user
    flash('Thanks for registering')
    # redirect user to the 'home' method of the user module.
    return redirect(url_for('users.home'))
  return render_template("users/register.html", form=form)
```

When I am launching the localhost through:

```
python run.py
```

I am getting 404 Not Found.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your run.py code? Most likely you have not configured a route for the '/' path.

Comment: Show your views.py file

Comment: @Spiderman - updated the question with the view.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't define a route for the root of your site.

```
@app.route('/')
def your_root_route():
    return "hello"
```

Comment: in the views.py?

Comment: Flask allows you a lot of flexibility with regard to how you structure your app. You can define it there if you want to, but you could basically define it just about anywhere. If you want to put it in views.py, you can. But again, it's not strictly required.